# Is there a way (command) to get a list of specific folders inside the parent folder?

Tags: linux

I have quite a bit of folders (more than 200) and I need a list of particular ones that has ".feat" in the end (they also contain subfolders that I do not need in the list). I was wondering if there is a way to sort them out somehow (in all subfolders)

UPD sorry it's linux! I was using "find . -type d *.feat" but it's almost impossible to filter out part of them that contain .feat only without subfolders in them.

I guess I need to edit depth to 3 subfolders maximum. The tree looks like  it is parental/CS/B1/1.feat/ 1/ and so on (generated by the soft)

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Sorry, it's linux! I added tags but forgot to mention in the main body

Comment: "Inside the parent folder" meaning "directly in the parent folder"? or "somewhere inside, no matter the depth"?

Comment: I am horrible at explaining. I am sorry. In all subfolders. There are various folders and when I try " find . -type d *.feat " I get all folders together mixed (as the command is for all folders )

Answer (score 1):

There is this question: [*How to find a directory on Linux?*](https://superuser.com/q/327762/432690) Not a perfect duplicate, because you also need to know how to use wildcards with `-name`. The command will be:

```
find . -type d -name '*.feat'
```

Note the quotes [are important](https://superuser.com/q/1217773/432690).

If you need to limit "depth to 3 subfolders maximum", use GNU `find` with its `-maxdepth`. If your `find` does not support `-maxdepth` then see [how to limit POSIX `find` to specific depth](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/275637/108618).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need something like :
`ls *.feat`

`ls` allows to get the list of files and directories in the current directory.
`*.feat` allows to restrict to files whose name ends with '.feat'.

If you wish to get only directories (i.e. not files), you can use the `--directory` option :
`ls --directory *.feat`

Example :

```
> mkdir test.feat test2.feat test test2 && ls --directory *.feat
test2.feat  test.feat
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It gives me the folders in parental directory only. The tree looks like parental/CS/B1/1.feat/ 1/ I was using "find . -type d *.feat" but it gives me subdirectories too

Comment: Then you can look at Kamil Maciorowski's answer, I think it fits what you need :)